# How to return a response from an API Route and use it on the client in the app router of Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

Of all the changes from Next.js 12 to 13, this is the most confusing. I have to look it up every time I want to make a fetch request because of all this JSON confusion. Can someone PLEASE help me once and for all?

I make a fetch POST request to the API handler like so:

```
//client component
const res = await fetch('/api/dostuff', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({dataObj: {hey: "ho"})
    })
//PLEASE HELP ME GET THE RESPONSE
```

I receive it like so:

```
//route.js in api/dostuff/
export async function POST(request) {

  const { dataObj } = await request.json()

  //PLEASE HELP ME RETURN THIS
  
}
```

I've tried like a hundred different variations between all the ultra-confusing json methods (`JSON.stringify`, `JSON.parse`, and the extra confusing `json()`), but nothing works. In Next.js 12 I didn't have to type the word "json" once.

Answer (score 2):

You can return plain text using the `Response` constructor:

```js
// api/route.js

export async function POST(request) {
  return new Response("Hello, Next.js!", {
    status: 200,
  });
}
```

Or return JSON, using `NextResponse` from `"next/server"`:

```js
// api/route.js

import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function POST(request) {
  return NextResponse.json({ message: "Succes" });
}
```

And consume the response on the client:

```js
const res = await fetch("/api/dostuff", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ dataObj: { hey: "ho" } }),
});
// For the first example (sending plain text):
const data = await res.text();
// For the second one (sending a JSON):
const data = await res.json();
```

For more, check out [Route Handlers](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers).

Comment: This is not true though? I have to do `new Response(JSON.stringify(dataObj, {status: 200})`? If not, why not?

Comment: If you want to send an object, use NextResponse.json(dataObj), as I said in the second case.

Comment: Hi @Yeats! Is your problem solved. Let us know please.